# Correct place to exend FLOW3 Bootstrap?

Tags: doctrine, bootstrapping, event-listener, typo3-flow

currently I am trying to register a Doctrine-Eventlistener for every request in my FLOW3-Package. Some research pointed me to the Package.php, but unfortunately the ObjectManager is not available when the boot()-Method is called.

I searched the whole FLOW3-Documentation http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/guide/partiii/bootstrapping.html without luck

Any hints on which is the right place to do package-wide setup with access to the object manager?

thanks and best regards

Comment: Better ask in the newsgroup or in the chat: `freenode -> #flow3`

Answer (score 0):

Your are bit to early in the bootstrap to get every object, I have a problem, maybe related to yours, you can check my bug report on http://forge.typo3.org/issues/33838

Why do you need a Doctrine Eventlistener, maybe you can use AOP to have this kind of feature ?